# Globablly Suppressing Stylecop Rules Not Working

Tags: code-analysis, asp.net-core-3.1, stylecop

I am working to implement stylecop to enforce our coding standard, however, there are a lot of stylecop rules that are outside our standards, for example, SA1309 FieldNamesMustNotBeginWithUnderscore.

Following [this example](https://damienaicheh.github.io/dotnet/xamarin/2019/06/20/use-stylecop-in-your-project-to-improve-your-code-quality-en.html) I added a rule disabling the FieldNamesMustNotBeginWithUnderscore rule like so

```
        <Rule Name="FieldNamesMustNotBeginWithUnderscore">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
```

to the Settings.StyleCop file I created.  However, I am still getting warnings for SA1309, even after a rebuild and reopening the project.

Other rules appear to work, for example,

```
        <Rule Name="ConstructorSummaryDocumentationMustBeginWithStandardText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
```

What's going on here?

Also, is there any way of globally disabling most/all rules that ship with stylecop?  Adding a rule xml like these for every rule we want to exclude is going to be a PITA, and if we could instead selectively enable the rules we want it would speed things up (especially if we could go by some larger grouping, like category)

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. In the latest Visual Studio (version 16.7.3), none of the supression methods through Visual Studio are doing anything! I would have thought, if I had disabled a rule, I'd get Visual Studio to generate me a `.ruleset` file, but that is **not happening**!